# Is there a good RPG with mechanics close to Crysis games

Tags: weapons, post-apocalyptic, invisibility

Is there a good RPG (or boardgame) with mechanics close to Crysis games? With stealth, super soldiers, aliens, customizable realistic weapons, and a postapocalyptic world.

I personally want a rpg with close to real battle mechanics, with two or three bullets almost certainly killing someone who isn't wearing armor, invisible, or attacking from stealth.

Comment: Do you want a specific one? Any of the universal systems will handle what you want without too much trouble. Is there a reason you don't want to play GURPS or HeroSystem? Also, be advised that 2-3 bullets and your dead makes for a *very* cautious game by the players.

Comment: Made some edits to fix language and localize the question to RPG.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several that can do fairly realistic combat exist. Lethality, however, is not the only axis to consider.

**GURPS** can be highly lethal, tho' it's native is that a bullet usually puts a man down, rather than kills him. It's also rather realistic in its approach to melee; of the games that I've played, it is one of the better for accurate melee. Point based character generation is, for some, highly realistic, for others, the height of surrealism. GURPS has many supplements covering a range of settings, and so at least one will be useful; not being familiar with the series described, I can only guess that GURPS: Special Ops, GURPS: High Tech, and maybe GURPS: Supers. If you want Cyberwear, GURPS Cyberpunk is also good. Most of these are for 3rd ed; 4th ed is slightly different in details, but still the same engine.

**CORPS** (by BTRC) is another universal system. Ranged combat is more realistic than GURPS' is,  the page count is much smaller, and there isn't the depth of setting books, but $30 gets you *CORPS* and *CORPS:VDS*, giving you vehicle design and core rules. *More Guns* includes more  real-world guns than you will probably ever need, and while it gives multiple sets of stats, CORPS was built around 3G3, and 3G3 was used to rate and/or rebuild the weapons in More Guns, so CORPS stats are present throughout. The system is highly lethal; a Good shot can kill quickly, and a decent shot will put a man down. Core rules include paranormal powers, which includes cybernetics, psionics, low-level supers.

**EABA** (by BTRC) is a redevelopment from first principles by the same author as CORPS. More dice use, but fairly realistic, and point based. Has more setting support than CORPS does. Core rules include vehicle, weapon, and superpowers, so it can do any genre.

**Phoenix Command** (by Leading Edge) is out of print, but is highly tactical and fairly realistic, but suffers from table-heaviness. I don't recommend it, as it's overly complex; I mention it for completeness. It does all the stuff requested...

**Traveller** can be used for the very tactical games in the genre; the current edition has the needed cyber and paranormal abilities in various books, and the character generation is career based. It's less lethal than CORPS, more so than GURPS. Vehicle design rules are published for several editions. Further, several editions have actual tactical minis games that are convertible or compatible. 
{CT has Snapshot compatibility, and AHL and Striker convertability; MT is capable of being played as a minis game as is; TNE has Striker II for small unit (Platoon-Company-Light Battalion) level combats; T4 has ACQ for Squad level combats}.

**Twilight: 2000** is available on CD from Far Future Enterprises. The Second Edition, combined with Dark Conspiracy, also available from FFE, gives a wide range of career based options with an extant post-apocalypse setting. DC gives the supersoldier tech. T2K was grounded in the 90's US Army. It's less lethal than any of the above, but a simple switch to D10's for damage fixes that. 
(Twilight 2013 is not Twilight 2000. Don't be fooled by the licensed imitation.)

As mentioned by others, **CP2020** can do it, it's comparable in lethality to EABA and GURPS. It's also OOP. The older **CP2013** is a much more lethal combat ruleset, and more fun to play in minis-on-map mode than CP2020. Both suffer badly, however, from class-based design. (The archetypes and their core skills define, functionally, classes with open skill choices but strong benefits in field from the archtype skills, like the Rockerboy's Charismatic Leadership and the Solo's Combat Sense.)

**Mekton** is a better choice than CP; same core rules, more lethality, and vehicle design and psionic rules. It doesn't include much cyberwear, but much cyber can be built with the Mekton Technical System (a separate supplement; called Mekton Technical System for Mekton II, and Mekton Zeta Plus for Mekton Zeta). The rules are written as a Mecha Anime game, but it readily handles non-mecha type combat vehicles. MTS can also build personal weapons.

**Heavy Gear** & **Jovian Chronicles** - the Silhouette System. There is a PA setting version - **Tribe 8** - and all three are the same rules system. Different fluff text, point based CharGen. Not quite as lethal, but very tactical, and a good hit can kill outright, or wound. No design system, per se, but a definite system of rating a design to come up with game stats that mesh up, yet allow for extraordinary tech above the baseline. HG is realistic mechan anime; 3m tall walkers are norm, 5m is about the tallest. JC started as a setting book for Mekton ... and later became a setting book for Heavy Gear, but got released as a stand-alone. Later versions of both include d20 system dual stats. There are two other settings (or more). The editions I got of JC and HG include both the minis game rules and the RPG rules, all using one cohesive system; Gear Kreig only has minis-level rules, and Tribe 8 only has RPG rules, but it is very simple to make the conversions and use materials across the line. Potential lethality is high, actual is lowered slightly for cinematic feel. With the right point totals, supersoldiers with hot toys can be readily done.

As mentioned by others, **SLA Industries** is a great setting, but it's not exactly Post-Apaocalyse, and it's a one-off system, and the combat isn't as lethal from what I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Interlock system used in **Cyberpunk 2.0.2.0.** by R.Talsorian Games. The system is fast and gritty, and combat is usually very quick and deadly. Technology is an integral part of the system, as well as human augmentation using cybernetics. It should fit the Crysis setting nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I have used it for so many different games now that it almost feels generic to me. :) It is very *tweakable*. Doesn't depend on delicate balancing acts with volumes of rulebooks.

Comment: It's the same core rules as Mekton, too. Or is that Mekton II. ;) And Mekton Z. I find CP2020 not really particularly lethal nor particularly realistic, but will note that it's a decent engine.

Comment: I know about Mekton Z but not the others. And it is lethal if you really apply the required modifiers and saves. (They don't stand out much in the book), and as I said, it is tweakable. If you restrict the attribute and starting skill ranges to human norms (a bit less than what CP2020 allows) it becomes much grittier.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SLA Industries.  It has cyberpunk elements, horror elements, and many many conspiracies.  The world is not linked at all to Crysis but an adaptation should be easy.

The [Home page](http://nightfall.co/) for the publishing house should give you more information.